# Elixir: what is the meaning of nil

Tags: null, elixir

I'm learning elixir and I was wondering if `nil` is the same as `null` in JavaScript, if not, what is the meaning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are similar, both are often used to denote the absence of a value. In JavaScript, `!!null` evaluates to `false`, while in Elixir, `!!nil` evaluates to `false`. Just like JavaScripts `null`, you can use `nil` as a "falsy" value in a boolean context, for instance:

```
if nil do
  IO.puts "foo"
else
  IO.puts "bar"
end
```

will print "bar"

I can't think of many differences between the two, other than perhaps a few corner cases. For instance, `null > 0` evaluates to `false` in JavaScript, while `nil > 0` evaluates to `true` in Elixir.

Comment: The fact that `nil > 0` evalates to true in Elixir, reminded me of Wat talk: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat :)

Comment: `nil` in Elixir is an atom: `is_atom(nil) #⇒ true`. (Actually, that makes `nil > 0` truthy.)

Comment: In Erlang it is obvious that `true`, `false` and `nil` are atoms however in Elixir it is less obvious (as the syntax is different), however you can test it on your own via `nil == :nil #=> true`.

Comment: it makes no sense to me that nil > 0 gives true. Any comparison with nil should return false.